# How to prevent commits in SVN that have log messages containing Chinese characters?

Tags: svn

I have access to the SVN server and i found the **pre-commit.tmpl** at directory **/home/.svn1/hooks**

I believe this is the file I am going to make changes to disallow commits with chinese messages

The file content is:

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

# Make sure that the log message contains some text.
SVNLOOK=/usr/local/bin/svnlook
$SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
   grep "[a-zA-Z0-9]" > /dev/null || exit 1

# Check that the author of this commit has the rights to perform
# the commit on the files and directories being modified.
commit-access-control.pl "$REPOS" "$TXN" commit-access-control.cfg || exit 1

# All checks passed, so allow the commit.
exit 0
```

How can I filter out Chinese characters?

Comment: Tell your programmers to use English for their log messages.

Comment: @KenWhite  Thanks. I already did this, but still want to put a check at the server

Comment: Sorry. There was supposed to be a ;-) at the end of the last comment.

Comment: Use chinese-chars range in grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change commit messages. If it is even possible you might alter the meaning of the message.
Better way is to prevent any commit messages violating your rules, in your case using Chinese characters.

If someone uses forbidden characters user will see a message and commit will be rejected.

This could be easily done with a pre-commit hook.

Therefore create a file **pre-commit** in your **.svn/hooks folder**. 
Use `svnlook` to check the commit for different parameters.
Do a `svnlook -h` to see what else can be done.

One simple example, checking if there is any character not in ASCII range:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

FOUND=$(svnlook log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | tr -d '\n' | grep  "[^\x00-\x7F]" )

if [ "$FOUND" != "" ]
then
    exit 0
else 
    echo "Reject commit! Do not use non ASCCI in commit messages!" 1>&2 && exit 1
fi
```

Comment: do I need to restart the svn to make changes effect?

Comment: it does not work for mixed chinese and english , strange

Comment: i think it should be $FOUND == ""  instead of !=